# Make network printer accessible from outside LAN

Tags: internet, wireless-router, port-forwarding, network-printer, dmz

I have an Epson L4150 printer that is perfectly accessible from inside my LAN, however I need it to accept print jobs from the internet (both from another home and from a Python script running in an AWS EC2 instance).

How can I do that without relying on a computer always on as a server? How do I actually access it after configuration?

My router (Archer c7 V5) offers a DMZ (which according to its webpage is not a true DMZ and just opens all ports), port forwarding and virtual servers. Which one would be a better option in my case?

Things that won't work:

- Printing from email: this printer doesn't have that feature.
- Not doing it: someone actually suggested this so I better add it just
  in case.
- Buying another printer: I want to use this one because the ink lasts
  ages and it's quite cheap.
- Using a home server: I don't have one.
- Using an old PC as a server: I    have no compatible screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Epson L4150 does support Epson's cloud print service, which usually just involves registering the printer on their website. From the [Manual](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd54034.pdf):

> Print from anywhere with these Epson Connect solutions:
>
> - Epson Email Print
> - Epson iPrint Mobile App
> - Epson Remote Print
> - Using Google Cloud Print

There are python modules for use with google cloud printing, (though I haven't touched it).

---

Don't port-forward ([virtual servers](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/Archer-C7/chapter-11-nat-forwarding#ug-sub-title-1) on their site) a printer *unless* you can limit who is allowed to connect by IP or something, but it looks like that is not supported by tp-link or your printer.

Your router does support hosting an [OpenVPN or PPTP](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/Archer-C7/chapter-12-vpn-server) tunnel. Clients like your ec2 instance could vpn into your home network and print to your printer like it's on the same network, without any extra hardware.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that without relying on a computer always on as a server?
> How do I actually access it after configuration?

**(1)** Put the Printer on the Network and not attached to a computer. Use a Print Server Box if needed.

**(2)** Install a VPN service so you can access your home network from wherever. If you have such, well and good and having Printer on your Network should allow you to print to it. You may need to log on to your home computer (any home computer) to have it do the printing. That is normal. A computer without a screen works - just log into it from afar. A screen is not needed for remote work. Any computer that is on will work.

I have done this for remote printing to my HP Printer.

It is not practical to print without a driver, so having some computer on is helpful and really necessary.

**(3)** For smart devices, if Air Print is supported, you can do that as well.

You normally cannot remote into just a printer on some network because of the lack of remote access drivers (unless specialized Cloud).